# Regex: Is it possible to replace a match with a repeated character

Tags: regex

I have tried Googling this several ways but keep coming back with the opposite of what I'm looking for. For the record, I am doing this in BBEdit's Search and Replace, but I think it will be a general regex answer.

Simple example: I want to add six tabs in front of a line. To *match* six tabs you can do:

```
\t{6}
```

Is it possible to insert six tabs in a similar manner? Like:

Search string:

```
^
```

Replace string:

```
\t{6}
```

Comment: You could do something like `repeat("\t", 6)` using a general programming language to construct the replace string.

Comment: Is there any reason for NOT using \t\t\t\t\t\t ? It does not look elegant, but it does the job.

Comment: @virolino That is exactly the reason. I have a number of these to format a document and it’s very hard to read mixed in with everything else. On top of that, it’s going into an AppleScript to drive BBEdit so all of the \ have to be escaped, as well as quotes. Makes for a lot of \.